# MqttException on Android

Tags: android, push-notification, mq

I have been following [Dale Lane's blog](http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=1599) to access Mosquitto through my Android project, but am stuck at the first step. Here is the relevant portion of the logs :

```
02-24 20:43:17.324: WARN/System.err(316): com.ibm.mqtt.MqttException
02-24 20:43:17.534: WARN/System.err(316):     at com.ibm.mqtt.MqttBaseClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
02-24 20:43:17.534: WARN/System.err(316):     at com.ibm.mqtt.MqttBaseClient.connect(Unknown Source)
02-24 20:43:17.534: WARN/System.err(316):     at com.ibm.mqtt.MqttClient.connect(Unknown Source)
02-24 20:43:17.534: WARN/System.err(316):     at com.ibm.mqtt.MqttClient.connect(Unknown Source)
02-24 20:43:17.534: WARN/System.err(316):     at com.push.MQTTService.connectToBroker(MQTTService.java:665)
02-24 20:43:17.584: WARN/System.err(316):     at com.push.MQTTService.handleStart(MQTTService.java:294)
02-24 20:43:17.584: WARN/System.err(316):     at com.push.MQTTService.onStartCommand(MQTTService.java:210)
02-24 20:43:17.594: WARN/System.err(316):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3053)
02-24 20:43:17.594: WARN/System.err(316):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3600(ActivityThread.java:125)
02-24 20:43:17.594: WARN/System.err(316):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2096)
02-24 20:43:17.594: WARN/System.err(316):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

02-24 20:43:20.107: WARN/System.err(316):     at com.ibm.mqtt.MqttBaseClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
02-24 20:43:20.107: WARN/System.err(316):     at com.ibm.mqtt.MqttBaseClient.connect(Unknown Source)
02-24 20:43:20.114: WARN/System.err(316):     at com.ibm.mqtt.MqttClient.connect(Unknown Source)
02-24 20:43:20.124: WARN/System.err(316):     at com.ibm.mqtt.MqttClient.connect(Unknown Source)
02-24 20:43:20.124: WARN/System.err(316):     at com.push.MQTTService.connectToBroker(MQTTService.java:665)
02-24 20:43:20.124: WARN/System.err(316):     at com.push.MQTTService.access$6(MQTTService.java:658)
02-24 20:43:20.124: WARN/System.err(316):     at com.push.MQTTService$NetworkConnectionIntentReceiver.onReceive(MQTTService.java:883)

02-24 20:43:20.274: WARN/System.err(316): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: /127.0.0.5:1883 - Connection refused
02-24 20:43:20.304: WARN/System.err(316):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:254)
02-24 20:43:20.344: WARN/System.err(316):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:533)
02-24 20:43:20.344: WARN/System.err(316):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1055)
02-24 20:43:20.344: WARN/System.err(316):     at com.ibm.mqtt.j2se.MqttJava14NetSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
02-24 20:43:20.344: WARN/System.err(316):     at com.ibm.mqtt.j2se.MqttJavaNetSocket.setConnection(Unknown Source)
02-24 20:43:20.376: WARN/System.err(316):     at com.ibm.mqtt.Mqtt.tcpipConnect(Unknown Source)

02-24 20:47:17.677: DEBUG/SntpClient(65): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

The exception is thrown at the "connectToBroker()" method of Dale's code :

```
mqttClient.connect("_unique_client_id", true, (short) 2000);     //tried many permutations
```

I am running Mosquitto broker on the same machine as the client. I can publish/subscribe to the broker through the IA92 client provided in the samples.I am also able to connect through a simple java project with the same service parameters.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Where are these errors reported that you have copied? adb log would be more useful in diagnosing the problem, as would an indication to which line in the code resulted in this exception. Are you using an emulator or a real device?

Comment: To simplify things, I wrote this class with a main method. I am getting this error on the console itself, the rest of the error is in the log file created by the error. I am not running the code on emulator yet.

Comment: The main method of what - a Service? Where are you running this code? Have you done any Android development before?

Comment: Sorry Dale, I am new to Android and was doing some silly mistakes. I am getting different set of errors now. I also tried running your app which you had earlier posted at http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=938 ..but I am getting the same error in that too. Thanks.

Comment: I'm on my phone, so a couple of quick thoughts until I'm next at my computer:  
1) Are you sure that you're using the right IP address for the broker? localhost/127.0.0.1 would work fine for clients on your dev computer, but obviously the same code wouldn't make sense on an Android device, as it'll be pointing at the android device. If you're using the emulator, 10.0.2.2 is the equivalent.
2) If you've got the IP address right, are you sure there isn't a firewall in the way of receiving connections on port 1883?

Comment: OMG ! I guess my being new to Android was all the problem...10.0.2.2 worked :) Thanks for your precious help. It feels great to see the app running...Thanks again !

Comment: Glad it helped - might be good if you could mark the question as answered now, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Dale, I just had to change the localhost address to 10.0.2.2, rest was all smooth.